# How can I store data for simple offline Desktop applcation?

Tags: java, database, windows-installer, storage, desktop-application

I have crated simple library management system in Java. Should I use database for my application ? If yes I use database, do my client also need to install database for using application ?. I have seen many software's who store data in windows app-data, my documents folder. I want to create software with simple Installer; Install and Run. Please help me about data storage options.

Comment: How many items do you need to track?  How do you need to access the items?   What kind of search facilities do you want?   The choice of storage mechanism comes after you've decided what you need to do, not as the first step, which it appears to be from this question.

Comment: I will store about 500 Books. Just simple search to see if book is present. Search to fetch books of same author. Add new book. Remove existing book. I want these facilities. I want my software to not lose data after computer shut down. please try answering my all questions. Thanks.

Comment: For 500 books a database is not needed.  Simple hashed in-memory structures will suffice, with code to load/save to a file at startup/exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the benefits of both using a database and having the application simple to install and run, if you use an "embedded" database engine.

An embedded database is just a library you add to your program. There is no external server that you have to manage. Internally, the data is stored in a file or files which you can place in an "application data" folder.

Popular choices for an embedded database system are [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) and [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/)